# tengo un problema, al leer la data de un archivo txt y transformar esta data a un archivo excel en python con la libreria openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, libreria

tengo mi codigo el cual me realiza el proceso, pero cuando necesito que me haga un salto de linea para escribir en la siguiente, siempre se queda sobreescribiendo la misa¿ma, que puedo hacer para resolver?

from variables import *
from classes.Resumen import Resumen
from typing import List
from variables import *
import os
import traceback
import openpyxl
import re

def getFormat(value: str, first: int, last: int) -> str:
return f"=SUM({value}{first}:{value}{last})"

class File:
def editFormtData(cells: list[str], fila_a: str, fila_init: str) -> list[str]:
newArray: list[str] = []
for cell in cells:
value = cell
if cell and isinstance(cell, str):
if str(fila_init) in value:
value = cell.replace(fila_init, fila_a)
newArray.append(value)
# print(value)
return newArray

```
# la hoja y la fila a copiar, y retorna la data de la celda en un array
def copyCell(sheet, fila) -> list[str]:
    cells = []
    for col in range(sheet.min_column, sheet.max_column+1):
        # print('cell',sheet.cell(row=fila, column=col).value)
        cells.append(sheet.cell(row=fila, column=col).value)
    return cells

# recibe un array con los campos de la delta, la hoja y la fila donde se va colar el valor
def pasteCell(data: list[str], sheet, fila):
    i = 0
    for col in range(sheet.min_column, sheet.max_column+1):
        sheet.cell(row=fila, column=col).value = data[i]
        i += 1

def validCell(value: str) -> bool:
    patron = r"\${resumen\.[a-zA-Z_]+}"
    if re.match(patron, value):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def getRow(sheet) -> int:
    fila = 0
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        fila += 1
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value and isinstance(cell.value, str):
                # print('cell', cell.value)
                if File.validCell(cell.value):
                    return fila

def generar_reporte_mensual(org: str, resumenes: List[Resumen], log):
    try:
        rutaPlantilla = rutaArchivoP + '\\' + "Plantillas" + \
            '\\' + f"Reporte_Mensual_{org}_plantilla.xlsx"
        output_path = rutaArchivoP + '\\' + "Reportes" + \
            '\\' + f"Reporte_Mensual_{org}.xlsx"

        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(rutaPlantilla)):
            print('No existe plantilla', rutaPlantilla)
            return

        out = os.path.join(output_path)

        # Crear un objeto Workbook y cargar la plantilla
        workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
        workbook.remove(workbook.active)
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(rutaPlantilla)

        # Seleccionar la hoja activa
        sheet = workbook.active

        fila = File.getRow(sheet)
        fila_base = fila

        # Copiar el formato de la celda origen
        formatData = File.copyCell(sheet, fila)

        # Eliminar al fila con el formato ya guardado
        sheet.delete_rows(fila)
        i = 1

        first = 4
        last = len(resumenes) + 4 - 1
        # formatF = getFormat('F', first, last)
        # print(formatF)
        for resumen in resumenes:
            i += 1
            sheet.insert_rows(fila)
            newFormDataByFila = File.editFormtData(formatData, str(fila), str(fila_base))
            File.pasteCell(newFormDataByFila, sheet, fila)
            for cell in sheet[fila]:
               if cell.value and isinstance(cell.value, str):
                    if "${resumen.afiliado}" in cell.value:
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace("${resumen.afiliado}", resumen.afiliado)
                    elif "${resumen.terminal}" in cell.value:
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace("${resumen.terminal}", resumen.terminal)
                    elif "${resumen.comercio}" in cell.value:
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace("${resumen.comercio}", resumen.comercio)
                    elif "${resumen.ubicacion}" in cell.value:
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace("${resumen.ubicacion}", resumen.ubicacion)
                    elif "=" not in cell.value:
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace(f"${{resumen.doeContador}}", str(resumen.doeContador))
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace(f"${{resumen.doeMonto}}", str(resumen.doeMonto))
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace(f"${{resumen.dbncContador}}", str(resumen.dbncContador))
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace(f"${{resumen.dbncMonto}}", str(resumen.dbncMonto))
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace(f"${{resumen.dpContador}}", str(resumen.dpContador))
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace(f"${{resumen.dpMonto}}", str(resumen.dpMonto))
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace(f"${{resumen.voeContador}}", str(resumen.voeContador))
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace(f"${{resumen.voeMonto}}", str(resumen.voeMonto))
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace(f"${{resumen.vbncContador}}", str(resumen.vbncContador))
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace(f"${{resumen.vbncMonto}}", str(resumen.vbncMonto))
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace(f"${{resumen.moeContador}}", str(resumen.moeContador))
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace(f"${{resumen.moeMonto}}", str(resumen.moeMonto))
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace(f"${{resumen.mbncContador}}", str(resumen.mbncContador))
                        cell.value = cell.value.replace(f"${{resumen.mbncMonto}}", str(resumen.mbncMonto))
                        cell.value = float(cell.value)

            fila += 1
        #  Totales
        for cell in sheet[fila]: # type: ignore
            if cell.value and isinstance(cell.value, str):
                if (cell.value.find('SUM') != -1):
                    cell.value = cell.value[::-1].replace(
                        '4'[::-1], str(last)[::-1], 1)[::-1]
         # Guardar el archivo de Excel generado
        workbook.save(out)
    except PermissionError:
        log.write(
            f"No se puede guardar el archivo {os.path.basename(out)} porque está siendo utilizado por otro programa." + '\n')
        print(
            f"No se puede guardar el archivo {os.path.basename(out)} porque está siendo utilizado por otro programa.")
    except Exception as err:
        # Captura cualquier excepción y escribe el mensaje de error en el archivo log.txt
        print(err)
        error_message = traceback.format_exc()
        log.write("Error: " + str(err) + "\n" + error_message + '\n')
```

Comment: cuando dices un salto de linea  que te refieres? por con un `worksheet.cell('A1').style.alignment.wrap_text = True` para ajustar a la celda y salto de linea `\n`

Comment: mi programa, es lo siguiente:
lee un archivo txt, el cual contiene informacion, donde este se transformara en un excel usando una plantilla base donde sigue una estructuracon unas variables dentro de la plantilla, el problema es que cuando se escribe el archivo, solo me guarda la primera linea y me la vuelve a sobreescribir y no salta a la siguiente linea para copiar los isguientes datos, ya que el txt tiene aproximadamente 14mil lineas.